# Bugzilla installation Error for Perl modules

Tags: perl, opensuse, bugzilla

While running *checksetup.pl* on Open Suse 42.1 getting error about Perl modules not found which are already installed.

What could be the reason for it?

```
Checking perl modules...
Checking for               CGI.pm (v3.51)     ok: found v3.63 
Checking for           Digest-SHA (any)       ok: found v5.84_01 
Checking for             TimeDate (v2.23)     ok: found v2.24 
Checking for             DateTime (v0.75)     not found 
Checking for    DateTime-TimeZone (v1.64)     not found 
Checking for                  DBI (v1.614)    ok: found v1.628 
Checking for     Template-Toolkit (v2.24)     ok: found v2.26 
Checking for         Email-Sender (v1.300011) not found 
Checking for           Email-MIME (v1.904)    ok: found v1.940 
Checking for                  URI (v1.55)     ok: found v1.60 
Checking for       List-MoreUtils (v0.32)     ok: found v0.416 
Checking for    Math-Random-ISAAC (v1.0.1)    ok: found v1.004 
Checking for           File-Slurp (v9999.13)  ok: found v9999.19 
Checking for              JSON-XS (v2.01)     ok: found v3.03
```

Comment: Most likely you have two instances of perl, and the one you are checking is not the one where the modules are installed.

Comment: is there any way to check how many instances are there?

Comment: What do you get form `type perl`, `perl -v`, and what's the shebang line of `checksetup.pl`? Does checksetup modify @INC or tweak `lib`?

Comment: type perl
perl is hashed (/usr/bin/perl)  

  
perl -v

This is perl 5, version 18, subversion 2 (v5.18.2) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi

Copyright 1987-2013, Larry Wall

Perl may be copied only under the terms of either the Artistic License or the
GNU General Public License, which may be found in the Perl 5 source kit.

Complete documentation for Perl, including FAQ lists, should be found on
this system using "man perl" or "perldoc perl".  If you have access to the
Internet, point your browser at http://www.perl.org/, the Perl Home Page.

Comment: You can start with `which -a perl`, which may show more than one version. Whatever command you've used to make yourself certain that those modules are installed must be using a different perl from the one you used to run `checksetup.pl` if I'm right. How did you do those two things? The other possibility, of course, is that you're mistaken about those modules.

Comment: @Borodin which -a perl gives output /usr/bin/perl   /usr/bin/X11/perl

Comment: @karan: And what is the shebang line of `checksetup.pl`

Comment: @Borodin it is #!/usr/bin/perl

Answer (score 0):

How did you test the modules are installed?

Your testing script does not just test the installation of the Perl modules but their version. Maybe you have `Email-Sender` but it wants version 1.300011 (or higher) for example, and your installed version may be lower.
You can check by doing `perldoc Email::Sender` (the version may be displayed), or running it: `perl -MEmail::Sender -e 'print $Email::Sender::VERSION,"\n";'`, or if all else fails have a look at the module source (`perldoc -m Email::Sender`), or alternatively check your OS tool for package management as your modules may have been installed through the OS (or manually, you did not specify).

Same for the other lines where it says "not found".

Comment: I checked with perldoc for all modules which are showing not installed by checksetup.pl and their version is >= the required by checksetup.pl.

Comment: Then the first comment by @Borodin is probably the explanation.